# Why is my Canvas not drawable after adding it to my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, lwjgl

I am writing a little game that uses a Canvas instance to draw on (in case it is familiar; I use the game library LWJGL).
Now I have created a main menu for my game that consists of a single JPanel, which I then add to my main game JFrame at the start of the game;

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Puzzler");
this.canvas = canvas;
this.jframe = frame;
canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
frame.setSize(640, 480);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Next, I create the main menu:

```
this.mainMenuPanel = new MainMenuPanel(this.main);
this.jframe.setSize(500, 170);
this.jframe.getContentPane().add(mainMenuPanel);
this.jframe.validate();
```

Finally, when the main menu wants to start the game, I try to replace the main menu's JPanel by a Canvas instance:

```
this.jframe.setVisible(false);
this.jframe.invalidate();
this.jframe.removeAll();
this.jframe.getContentPane().add(canvas);
this.jframe.setVisible(true);
this.jframe.pack();
this.jframe.setSize(640, 480);
this.jframe.validate();
```

And when this final bit of code runs, the call to the LWJGL's Display.create() returns an error that the Canvas is not drawable.
I have tried a whole bunch of combinations (like adding a JPanel as the container of the Canvas, no luck), and been messing with the orders of the validate() and repaint() calls quite a bit as that sometimes helps in swing. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem here?

**EDIT**
I have solved the problem. The issue turned out to be that java's event handling thread got stuck at running the main loop, because I called run() on my main thread rather than start(). Silly me. :P

Comment: dont bother with the sscce, the tutorial page seems to have one :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: My repository lies here: git@github.com:bartvbl/CoopPuzzler.git.
The interesting files are client.clientWindow and client.gui.MainMenuPanel (with its related MainMenuView). ClientWindow handles the window stuff, and MainMenuPanel is the JPanel making up the main menu. I did manage now to get the canvas to resize, but for some strange reason when LWJGL retrieves the canvas size it gets (0, 0), and crashes.

Comment: not really keen on wading through tons of files ;-) Lets stick to the example in the tutorial - which runs fine in a JFrame (see edit2)

Comment: okay, changed the main to mimic replacing a intro (main menu) panel by the canvas. That's about how far I'm willing to go, hope it helps you to find the problem in your code :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: I have solved the problem. I used the run() method on the main thread I created, which made the java AWT event handling thread stuck on waiting for the main loop to finish. Changing that to start() resulted in a perfectly working game. Thanks again for the help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apart from the not-mixing rule, my guess is you would get a similar exception in a pure awt context - from LWJGL [tutorial Basic applet](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Basic_LWJGL_Applet):

> Now that we have the basic template we need to stick the LWJGL native
>   Display on it. To do this we simply use the Display.setParent(Canvas)
>   method. However before we can create the Display we need to make sure
>   that the canvas is ready to be drawn on. To ensure this we will use
>   the addNotify() method of the awt canvas to tell us when the canvas is
>   ready and that we can create the Display. Similarly we will use the
>   removeNotify() to inform us that the canvas is about to be destroyed
>   and we should clean up and close the native Display.

**Edit**

(still no IDE at hand, just from the top of my head ;-)

Actually, I don't quite understand what you are doing with all that removeXX, wouldn't expect any need to. At first, I would keep it simple and exactly as showing in the tutorial:

```
 display_parent = new Canvas() {
    public final void addNotify() {
       super.addNotify();
       startLWJGL();
    }
    public final void removeNotify() {
      stopLWJGL();
      super.removeNotify();
    }
 };
 frame.add(display.parent);
```

Plus make sure all changes happen on the EDT - which might be the real problem, don't know what Display actually does in those methods:

```
 public void gameLoop() {
     while(running) {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 Display.sync(60);
                 Display.update();
             }
         });
    }

    Display.destroy();
 }
```

**Edit 2**

just run the example (in the tutorial cited above) in a JFrame, no change to the existing code, just added a main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gears AWT");

        final JPanel intro = new JPanel();
        Action action = new AbstractAction("Start Gears") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                GearsApplet gears = new GearsApplet();
                gears.init();
                frame.remove(intro);
                frame.add(gears);
                frame.getRootPane().revalidate();
            }
        };
        JButton button = new JButton(action);
        intro.add(button);
        frame.add(intro); //.display_parent);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

feels okay (in first approximation, suspect there are some devils hiding in the darker niches of threading - as we are *not* on the EDT (most probably)), the gears are running and the group is rotatable

Comment: I did not, actually. I added the main menu after I finished the game itself; it runs like a charm without the swing code. However, once I add the JPanel containing the main menu, it throws the error.

Comment: @Bartvbl serves me right, freely guessing :-) hmm .. did you try to override addnotify? Random musings going on (my netbook is not a reasonable programming environment <g>: in the back of my mind is a bit of info that mixing is easier in current jdks (> 1.6u10)

Comment: Hm. I must say that I am not particularly familiar with applets; I only really write stuff for the desktop. Though I do seem to remember that applets have some different ways of drawing and general working. Perhaps the addNotify() is one of them? Or does it also count for regular applications?

Comment: hold on.. I just replaced the "removeAll()" by "remove(mainMenuJPanel)". Now the canvas displays, and so does the game drawn on top of it. The window itself is copletely frozen though. It does not resize, and only draws the canvas at the window's original size :/

Comment: @klweopatra: The remove() method is for getting rid of the JPanel holding the main menu. There is no problem displaying the game fine and creating LWJGL's openGL context. The thing is that it breaks once I add the JPanel to the equation; the window's contents just hang, and the closing button of the window does absolutely nothing.

Comment: I tried out the canvas with the overridden methods. The window/canvas did not behave any different :( Grats for writing code out of the top of your head though ;)

Answer (score 3):

Don't mix swing and awt components. Canvas is awt. Use the JPanel overriding `paintComponent Graphics g)` method.

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14718

Comment: Hmm. That could indeed be why it does not behave. I'll go take a look.

Comment: shouldn't be much of a problem since jdk 6u12 (didnt test, though) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit#Mixing_AWT_and_Swing_components